# Creating a marginal tcolorbox from inside an other tcolorbox

Tags: margins, tcolorbox

I have created a new `tcbtheorem`like this:

```
\usepackage[breakable, theorems, skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{enhanced}

\newtcbtheorem
    [number within = chapter]
    {myexample}
    {examples}
    {   breakable,
        colback=green!5,
        colframe=green!35!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        shadow={1mm}{-1mm}{0mm}{black!50!white}
    }
    {ex}


\newcommand{\cmmNormalExample}[3]{
    \begin{myexample}{#1}{#2}
        {#3}
    \end{myexample}
}

\newcommand{\cmmMarginalExample}[3]{
   \marginpar{
       \cmmNormalExample{#1}{#2}{#3}
   }
}
```

with the second command (\cmmMarginalExample) trying to create a box in the margin.
The stand-alone use of the above commands is ok but, when I use this command from inside the first one, for example:

```
\cmmNormalExample{Title A}{exlabelA}{
   blah, blah, ...

   \cmmMarginalExample{Title B}{exlabelB}{
     this must (i.e. "I want to") be in the margin
   }

   blah, blah, ...
}
```

I get the error: `"! Latex Error: Not in outer par mode."`

Any suggestions to skip this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Konstantinos Pavlou.

Answer (score 3):

There are two keys to this approach.  One is to dispense with `\marginpar` and instead use a combination of `\leftskip` and resetting `\linewidth`.  The second requirement is to add `nobeforeafter` option to your `tcolorbox` so that the box is placed "in the raw" and not pre/post -pended with extraneous commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[breakable, theorems, skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{enhanced}
\usepackage{calc}

\newtcbtheorem
    [number within = chapter]
    {myexample}
    {examples}
    {   breakable,nobeforeafter,
        colback=green!5,
        colframe=green!35!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        shadow={1mm}{-1mm}{0mm}{black!50!white}
    }
    {ex}


\newcommand{\cmmNormalExample}[3]{
    \begin{myexample}{#1}{#2}
        {#3}
    \end{myexample}
}

\newsavebox{\mymargbox}
\newcommand{\cmmMarginalExample}[3]{%
   \sbox{\mymargbox}{\vbox{%
       \linewidth=1.6in%
       \cmmNormalExample{#1}{#2}{#3}%
   }}
   \leftskip 2in%
   \usebox{\mymargbox}
   \leftskip -2in%
  \vspace*{-\ht\mymargbox}%
}
\begin{document}
\cmmNormalExample{Title A}{exlabelA}{
   blah, blah, ...

   \cmmMarginalExample{Title B}{exlabelB}{%
     this must (i.e. "I want to") be in the margin%
   }

   blah, blah, ...
}
\end{document}
```

enter image description here

[image]