# Is there a way to get correct eso-pic image placement within a tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, eso-pic

Apologies for lack of MWE - this is an issue I'm trying to work around in PreTeXt-generated LaTeX, which is not so minimal.

I have a book project using PreTeXt, where we want to place some figures in the margin.
I'm doing this with the `eso-pic` package, and code that looks like:

```
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(427,\LenToUnit{0.5\paperheight}){
\begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}
\begin{figure-ptx}...\end{figure-ptx}
\end{minpage}}}
```

This works quite well, despite the minor annoyance of having to manually set the vertical position for each of 500+ figures. (The 0.5 sets this in the middle of the margin.)

But many of the figures in the book occur within an example.
The `\begin{example}...\end{example}` environment created by PreTeXt is a tcolorbox.

If an example spans more than one page, the code above ends up placing the figure on the page before the example begins, rather than in the middle of the example.

Is there a way to change the page that the figure lands on in this setting?
(I am not committed to the eso-pic package and am willing to consider alternatives. We had been doing this with the `marginnote` package and this is an experiment to see if this is better.)

Edit: the main issue is that when `\AddToShipoutPicture*` is used within a tcolorbox spanning multiple pages, the page reference is taken from the beginning of the tcolorbox, rather than the page where the figure should be located.

I've found a way to do this using a tcolorbox instead.

Comment: Does the actual code to place the figure occur somewhere in the middle of the your `example` (`tcolorbox`) environment?

Comment: why can't you add the image to the example rather than add it to the page then have to set the coordinate to wherever the example landed?

Comment: @Werner: Yes, the code occurs in the middle of the `example` environment. When outputting from PreTeXt source to other formats (HTML, EPUB) the image is placed inline. But in PDF we'd like to move it to the margin, at roughly the same location.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: this is a conversion of a book written originally in LaTeX to PreTeXt. Most students don't print the book, so we want the better electronic formats provided by PreTeXt. But the original author would like to keep some of the styling from the legacy LaTeX version, and that includes placing figures and asides in the margin, rather than inline.
If there is another way to move the image to the margin, I will happily abandon this method, which is based on the code from the original LaTeX version of the book.

Comment: you could use `\pdfsavepos` and `\pdflastypos` to get (on the next run) the vertical position (there are lots of examples on site)

Comment: Thanks -- I had never heard of those; I'll look into it. I am guessing I still need to use that in conjunction with the  `put` command from `eso-pic` but maybe not. The difficulty I'm having is that when an example runs from page `n` to page `n+2`, and I want a figure in the margin on page `n+1`. Leaving the figure inside (or before) the example places it on page `n`. Moving it to the end of the example places it on page `n+2`. I can reposition vertically within a page, but can't move to the next/previous page.

Comment: OK, good and bad news. Using `\pdfsavepos` (once I figured out how to convert units) will save me a bit of trouble in terms of having to manually position items in the margin. (Good) But the `\AddToShipoutPicture*` command still does not always get the correct pageref. Sometimes things are placed 1 or 2 pages sooner than they should be.

Comment: This does not answer my original question on how to get the correct pageref inside a tcolorbox, but (with some very heavy modification) I have been able to adapt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137006/creating-a-marginal-tcolorbox-from-inside-an-other-tcolorbox) into a working solution using only tcolorbox.