# Can I avoid indentation of margin items when using parbox=false in a tcolorbox?

Tags: margins, tcolorbox, parbox, xcoffins

For a book project, examples, theorems, etc. are all styled using `tcolorbox`. (This part is not really negotiable -- the LaTeX code is generated by PreTeXt.)

I've been trying to figure out how to get some figures, as well as asides, into the margin.

My most recent attempt used `eso-pic`, but I ran into a problem: if the figure I want to be in the margin is part of an example (which is a tcolorbox environment) that spans 3 pages, I can't get a figure on the second page. (The `\AddToShipoutPicture*` command takes its page reference from the top of the tcolorbox.)

I found [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137006/creating-a-marginal-tcolorbox-from-inside-an-other-tcolorbox), which creates a tcolorbox in the margin for the figure/aside.

This does almost exactly what I want. But the `example` tcolorbox uses the option `parbox=false`, because we want paragraphs in an example. With this option present, the figure in the margin gets indented by 30pt.

Is there a way to avoid this, other than using separate environments for figures inside/outside an example? Here is an example to illustrate:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[breakable, theorems, skins]{tcolorbox}
%\tcbset{enhanced}
\usepackage[showframe,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\geometry{inner=1in,textheight=9in,textwidth=320pt,marginparwidth=150pt,marginparsep=20pt,bottom=1in,footskip=29pt}


\newtcbtheorem[number within = section]{myexample}{Example}%
    {breakable,
    colback=white, colbacktitle=white, coltitle=black,
        parbox=false,}{ex}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{myfig}{My Theorem}%
    {colback=white, colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black,
     fonttitle=\bfseries,
     }{th}    

\newsavebox{\mymargbox}
\newcommand{\marginfig}[1]{%
\sbox{\mymargbox}{\vbox{%
       \linewidth=\marginparwidth%
       #1%
   }}
   \ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}{
   \leftskip -325pt%
   \usebox{\mymargbox}
   \leftskip 325pt%
   }
   {\leftskip 186pt%
   \usebox{\mymargbox}
   \leftskip -186pt%
   }
  \vspace*{-\ht\mymargbox}
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{myexample}{title}{label}
{
\lipsum[1]

\par

\lipsum[2]

{

\marginfig{
\begin{myfig}{title2}{label2}
\begin{itemize}
\item An item
\item Another item
\item A somewhat longer item that is a bit longer than the margin width
\end{itemize}
\end{myfig}
}

}

\lipsum[5]
}
\end{myexample}

{

\marginfig{
\begin{myfig}{title3}{label3}
\begin{itemize}
\item An item
\item Another item
\item A somewhat longer item that is a bit longer than the margin width
\end{itemize}
\end{myfig}
}

}


\lipsum[1-2]

{

\marginfig{
\begin{myfig}{title4}{label4}
\begin{itemize}
\item An item
\item Another item
\item A somewhat longer item that is a bit longer than the margin width
\end{itemize}
\end{myfig}
}

}

\lipsum[3]

\par

\begin{myexample}{Title5}{label5}
\lipsum[2]


{

\marginfig{
\begin{myfig}{title6}{label6}
\begin{itemize}
\item An item
\item Another item
\item A somewhat longer item that is a bit longer than the margin width
\end{itemize}
\end{myfig}
}

}

\end{myexample}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of MWE]

Comment: Not a global solution, but if I drop `\hskip0pt` in front of the `\marginfig` command (or just inside), it removes the indentation. (Not global because if I put it in the macro definition, the boxes that weren't affected before get shifted out of the margin.) I also wish I could do away with the braces and whitespace wrapping around each `\marginfig` but without them, all the text following the `\marginfig` gets pulled into the margin. (Which is to say that I don't fully understand this macro...)

Comment: On the plus side, my LaTeX is written via XSL transform from PreTeXt XML source. So I can use an `<xsl:if>` that looks up the tree to see if a `figure` is a descendent of `example`. If yes, it writes in the `\hskip`.

Comment: I updated the code to correct some minor issues. Please try it.

(1) Please check that everything works changing the page geometry: `textwidth`, `marginparwidth`,`marginparsep`.

(2) Still missing: automatic horizontal alignment from inside the tcolorbox (the Example enviroment), if `boxsep` or the inner margins change.

Thank you for your feedback. It is always a pleasure to contribute to a real world project.

Comment: New update to version 3. I think I calculate everything in the correct way. No more hardwired dimensions. Try the new v3 code by changing the `boxsep`.

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much. I got v2 working properly, so I'm happy with that. I will try v3 though to see if that works once I'm in a more complicated setting. With v2, only issue I saw was sometimes a margin box at the bottom of one page gets dropped to the next page, but on the wrong side. Not unexpected. Some adjusting with `\pagebreak` or moving the box up a paragraph will take care of that.

Comment: The main change in v3 is that I got rid of the 5.5mm, which makes me very happy! You might try using also the vertical shift to place the margin box in the right place.

Comment: I will test and let you know. Won't be for a few days -- technically on holiday the next week. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose another approach (much easier to understand) to put the theorem boxes on the margin.

Using the package `xcoffin` you can put any material anywhere on the page. The reference point is the current insertion point.

Because there are some theorems that come from inside a tcolorbox and others from the text area, it takes two macros to account for the different margins involved.

(1) `\insertTheoBox{<content>}{<vertical shift>}`

(2) `\insertTheoPara{<content>}{<vertical shift>}`

The vertical shift allows for a vertical displacement inside the margin area.

Two inner "boxes" are used in the macros: `\Framex` is a zero depth box that allows for the `\Theox` box to be joined at a proper position.

The result of the assembly  is then typeset into the margin area.

[image: x]

**UPDATED** Minor issues corrected. No hardwired dimensions.

```
%%%% version 3

\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[breakable, theorems, skins]{tcolorbox}
%\tcbset{enhanced}
\usepackage[showframe,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\geometry{inner=1in,textheight=9in,textwidth=320pt,marginparwidth=150pt,marginparsep=20pt,bottom=1in,footskip=29pt}

\newtcbtheorem[number within = section]{myexample}{Example}%
{breakable,
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=white,
    coltitle=black,
    parbox=false,
 %  boxsep=14mm,  % for testing
}{ex}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{myfig}{My Theorem}%
{colback=white, colbacktitle=white,coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
}{th}  


%%*************************************************************** v3
\usepackage{xcoffins} %added
\NewCoffin\Framex
\NewCoffin\Theox

\usepackage{changepage} %added
\strictpagecheck

\newlength{\Textw} % save textwidth outside the boxes
\setlength{\Textw}{\textwidth}
\newlength{\Hshift}
\newlength{\Mshift}

\newcommand*{\calculateMshift}{%
    \checkoddpage
    \ifoddpage
        \setlength{\Mshift}{\marginparsep}
    \else
        \setlength{\Mshift}{\dimexpr-\marginparsep-\textwidth-\marginparwidth\relax}
    \fi}

    \newcommand*{\calculateHshift}{%
    \checkoddpage
    \ifoddpage
        \setlength{\Hshift}{\dimexpr\Textw/2-\tcbtextwidth/2\relax}
    \else
        \setlength{\Hshift}{\dimexpr-\Textw/2+\tcbtextwidth/2\relax}
    \fi}
    
\newcommand{\insertTheoBox}[2]{% v2 updated         
    \par %start a new line
    \calculateMshift
    \calculateHshift    
    \SetHorizontalCoffin\Framex{\color{blue}\rule{\tcbtextwidth}{0pt}} %clear box Framex
    \SetVerticalCoffin\Theox{\marginparwidth}{#1}% fill box \Theox
    \JoinCoffins*\Framex[r,vc]\Theox[l,vc](\dimexpr\Mshift+\Hshift\relax,#2)%join boxes
    \noindent\TypesetCoffin\Framex\\[-2\baselineskip] %typeset assembly
}

\newcommand{\insertTheoPara}[2]{% v2 updated
    \par
    \calculateMshift    
    \SetHorizontalCoffin\Framex{\color{red}\rule{\textwidth}{0pt}}
    \SetVerticalCoffin\Theox{\marginparwidth}{#1}
    \JoinCoffins*\Framex[r,vc]\Theox[l,vc](\Mshift,#2)  
    \noindent\TypesetCoffin\Framex\\[-2\baselineskip]
}
%%***************************************************************

\begin{document}    

    \begin{myexample}{title}{label}
        1. \lipsum[1]           
        \insertTheoBox{%
            \begin{myfig}{title1}{label1}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item An item
                    \item Another item
                    \item A somewhat longer item that is a bit longer than the margin width
                \end{itemize}
            \end{myfig}
        }{70pt}         
                
    2.  \lipsum[2]          
    \insertTheoBox{%
        \begin{myfig}{title2}{label2}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item An item
                \item Another item
                \item A somewhat longer item that is a bit longer than the margin width
            \end{itemize}
        \end{myfig}
    }{50pt}
            
    3.  \lipsum[5]      
    \end{myexample}

    \insertTheoPara{%       
    \begin{myfig}{title3}{label3}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item An item
            \item Another item
            \item A somewhat longer item that is a bit longer than the margin width
        \end{itemize}
    \end{myfig}
        }{-40pt}    

    
    4.  \lipsum[1-2]                    
    \insertTheoPara{%
    \begin{myfig}{title4}{label4}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item An item
            \item Another item
            \item A somewhat longer item that is a bit longer than the margin width
        \end{itemize}
    \end{myfig}
    }{-20pt}
    
    5.  \lipsum[3]  
    
        \insertTheoPara{%
        \begin{myfig}{title5}{label7}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item An item
                \item Another item
                \item A somewhat longer item that is a bit longer than the margin width
            \end{itemize}
        \end{myfig}
    }{-250pt}
    
    \begin{myexample}{Title5}{label5}
    6.  \lipsum[2]  
    
        \insertTheoBox{%
        \begin{myfig}{title6}{label6}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item An item
                \item Another item
                \item A somewhat longer item that is a bit longer than the margin width
            \end{itemize}
        \end{myfig}
    }{60pt}     
            
    \end{myexample}
\end{document}
```

The margin boxes and their positions will automatically adjust to changes in the page geometry or the internal geometry of the boxes in the text area.

For the next figure

```
\geometry{inner=1in,textheight=9in,
    textwidth=220pt, % changed <<<<<
    marginparwidth=220pt,  % changed <<<<<
    marginparsep=40pt,  % changed <<<<<
    bottom=1in,footskip=29pt}

    \newtcbtheorem[number within = section]{myexample}{Example}%
{breakable,
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=white,
    coltitle=black,
    parbox=false,
    boxsep=14mm,  % added <<<<<
}{ex}
```

[image: y]

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at that package. Main concern with adding packages is making sure it plays nicely with everything else. (This is a large book, with PreTeXt-generated .tex source: about 100,000 lines of LaTeX, and 1000 of that is preamble.) The vertical shift is a nice feature though: there's always a bunch of hand-editing needed to adjust page breaks and margin figures.

Comment: Updating my XSL now to write this in. I'll rebuild my LaTeX overnight and if I don't see any weirdness when I compile in the morning, I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: Everything is working beautifully in a test article, with everything I've thrown at it so far. When I try to do it in my book, the first block is placed correctly, but the next one is placed to the right of it, instead of below it! Horizontal placement is sort of all over the place.

Comment: @Sean Fitzpatrick Hard to tell without a complete code to test myself. The two blocks are inside a tcolobox or in pure text?

Comment: The problem seems to be that the marco was getting inserted without leading whitespace. If I put a blank line above the macro call, I can avoid that problem. The macro within the example environment has some horizontal alignment issues but hopefully I can fix that with some tinkering.

Comment: @Sean Fitzpatrick The final assembly is inserted in the current insertion point. For the relative positions to work it should be the the start of a paragraph. I will post an update to prevent this issue.  The horizontal alignment from inside the tcolorbox is tricky because depends on the values of boxsep, left, right, etc.. With the default values a magic number 5.5mm appears. I do not like to have it hardwired so I am trying to calculate it. .

Comment: That's great, thank you! I can just run with the `showframe` option turned on in the geometry package to make sure things line up, and adjust the numbers as needed